# How to increase QTableWidget Vertical Scrollbar width?

Tags: qt

I'm having a QTableWidget with more than 5000 datas. Now i need to increase the width of vertical scrollbar associated with the QTableWidget. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that with a style sheet:

```
myTableWidget->verticalScrollBar()->setStyleSheet(
    "QScrollBar:vertical { width: 100px; }");
```

See also [Customizing QScrollBar](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add following code in style sheet

```
QSrcollBar::vertical{width:50px;}
```