# Changing the width of a scrollbar in a Qt/PySide text area element

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside, qtgui

I'm writing a Qt/Pyside interface for a touchscreen. In a QTextEdit element, I'd like to increase the width of the vertical scrollbar. I couldn't find an obvious way of doing this; any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase QTableWidget Vertical Scrollbar width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411761/how-to-increase-qtablewidget-vertical-scrollbar-width)  - stylesheets will do the trick

Comment: Yes, duplicate. It die solve my problem.