# How to change the size of a QComboBox's QScrollBar?

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I'm using a QComboBox with some items to the point that, when the widget that shows all available items in the QComboBox appears, only some of the items are visible with the other accesible through a QScrollBar.

The problem is that the QScrollBar is to thin and I want to make it larger. I did some research on the web and I did found some ways to change the QScrollBar's width (see references below), but the problem is that I simply can't find the method to access the QComboBox's QScrollBar.

So, given this problem, how can I do this change? (I guess you may either present me with a way that don't require me to access the QScrollBar or show how may I access it).

References:

- [vertical scrollbar width](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/7514-vertical-scrollbar-width) - Direct access and style
- [How to get scroll bar real width in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515646/how-to-get-scroll-bar-real-width-in-qt) - Again by pixlMetric (only access)
- [How to increase QTableWidget Vertical Scrollbar width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411761/how-to-increase-qtablewidget-vertical-scrollbar-width) - Using stylesheet (a preferable method if there is a way to make it apply to all QScrollBars available in the project)
- [Other options are discussed here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/339)

Comment: Just idea: try to set model with data to your box, create listView, try to customize it and setView to combo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get the combobox's `QAbstractItemView` via [view()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#view)
2. That class inherits from `QAbstractScrollArea`, thus inherits the [verticalScrollBar method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#verticalScrollBar)

e.g.

```
QAbstractItemView *qv = combobox.view();
QScrollBar *scrollbar = qv->verticalScrollBar();
// Adjust size via setStyleSheet or hint/width
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although it worked when compiling to Desktop, it didn't work for my Ebedded Linux Qt compilation =T I'll create a specific thread in Stack Overflow to deal with this issue, since compilation with Desktop worked well and, therefore, your solution works.

Answer (score 2):

The scroll bar isn't a member of the QComboBox class, it's a member of the underlying QAbstractItemView. Try something like the following (pseudo-code):

```
QListView* abby = new QListView();
QWidgetList list = abby->scrollBarWidgets(Qt::AlignRight);
for (auto itr = list.begin(); itr != list.end(); itr++)
{
    (*itr)->setMinimumWidth(100);
}
QComboBox combo;
combo.setView(abby);
```

The scrollbarwidgets returns a widget list of the scroll bars for that alignment. You can then set the properties on the scroll bar pointers.