# QCombBox: How to show the the scroll-bar in dropdown list automatically

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

Means the dropdown needs to be scrollable depending on the resolution. Don’t need to show the scroll-bar, if we have space to make the dropdown taller to show all contents.

Comment: Isn't that the default behaviour?

Comment: using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047184/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-qcomboboxs-qscrollbar, try:

    `QAbstractItemView *qv = combobox.view();
    QScrollBar *scrollbar = qv->verticalScrollBar();
    scrollbar->setVisible(false);`